# Split description into multiple rows

Tags: sql, function, sas, dataset, sas-macro

I'm trying to accomplish the following in SAS.

My dataset looks like this:

```
|ID  |Description
|----|-----------------
| 1  |Object Car_bmw Processed.Colour changed from Red to Green Mileage changed from 30 to 32 Object Car_Audi Processed.Colour changed from Blue to White Mileage changed from 0 to 5
| 2  |Object Car_Kia Processed. Colour changed from White to Black Mileage changed from 3 to 9 Value changed from 12034 to 11029
| 3  |Object Phone_Iphone Processed. Colour changed from Black to Green Value changed from 300 to 290 Object Car_bmw Processed. Colour changed from White to Red Mileage changed from 100 to 50
```

I would like to create a new object column which will split the "description" column into so:

```
|ID  |Index| Description
|----|-----|-----------
| 1  | 1   | Object Car_bmw Processed.Colour changed from Red to Green Mileage changed from 30 to 32
|  1 | 2   | Object Car_Audi Processed.Colour changed from Blue to White Mileage changed from 0 to 5                                
| 2  | 1   | Object Car_Kia Processed.Colour changed from White to Black Mileage changed from 3 to 9 Value changed from 12034 to 11029
| 3  | 1   | Object Phone_Iphone Processed.Colour changed from Black to Green Value changed from 300 to 290 
| 3  | 2   | Object Car_bmw Processed. Colour changed from White to Red Mileage changed from 100 to 50
```

I tried using the following functions to separate the objects and "descriptions" into different rows. I used "Processed." as a delimiter since that is common between the different objects. However, it didn't work

```
data want;
set have;
do index = 1 to countw(LOG_LONG_DESC,'Processed.');
line_part = dequote(scan(LOG_LONG_DESC,index,'Processed.'));
OUTPUT;
end;
run;
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to use uppercase P and lowercase c,d,e,o,r and s as the set of possible delimiter characters.

Comment: Can you share the actual data instead of photographs?  Is there some delimiter character that is making what look like line breaks in the cells in your pictures?

Comment: There is no delimiter. However the line breaks are present. I believe the program from which the data is extracted creates a line break for each change that occurs on the object

Comment: If there is a break then there is a delimiter. Probably CR, '0D'x or LF, '0A'x.

Comment: To find your delimiter, print your text with a hex format and look for the codes from @Tom's comment.   `format log_long_desc hex32.;` Since you seem to have key word delimiters you could use FINDW to split as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is some delimiter between the lines in original photograph then I would recommend splitting it into one observation per line and making a second variable that increments when the word PROCESSED appears in the line.

Let's make a sample dataset that is using CR as the delimiter between the lines.

```
data have;
  length id 8 description $400;
  id=1;
  description='Object Car_bmw Processed.' || '0D'x
            ||'Colour changed from Red to Green' || '0D'x 
            ||'Mileage changed from 30 to 32' || '0D'x
            ||'Object Car_Audi Processed.' || '0D'x
            ||'Colour changed from Blue to White' || '0D'x 
            ||'Mileage changed from 0 to 5'
  ;
  output;
run;
```

Now we can use COUNTW() and SCAN() to split it into lines and FINDW() to detect when a line has PROCESSED in it.

```
data want;
  set have;
  group=0;
  do lineno=1 to countw(description,'0D'x);
    length line $100;
    line=scan(description,lineno,'0D'x);
    if findw(line,'processed',,'spit') then group+1;
    output;
  end;
  drop description;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    id    group    lineno                  line

 1      1      1         1      Object Car_bmw Processed.
 2      1      1         2      Colour changed from Red to Green
 3      1      1         3      Mileage changed from 30 to 32
 4      1      2         4      Object Car_Audi Processed.
 5      1      2         5      Colour changed from Blue to White
 6      1      2         6      Mileage changed from 0 to 5
```